# How do I install Sklearn for Reinteract?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, scikit-learn

I want to use [Reinteract](http://www.reinteract.org/) to develop a machine-learning application. I'd like to use Sklearn's svm module, but when I run

```
import sklearn.svm
```

I get

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm__init__.py", line 13,
>   in 
>       from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\classes.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 2, in
>   
>       import scipy.sparse as sp ImportError: No module named sparse

Similarly, when I run

```
import sklearn.cluster
```

I get

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster__init__.py", line
>   6, in 
>       from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\spectral.py", line
>   11, in 
>       from ..base import BaseEstimator, ClusterMixin   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in 
>       from scipy import sparse ImportError: cannot import name sparse

I am able to run

```
import sklearn
```

without error.

Reinteract on my Windows 7 machine is using

- sys.version = 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32
  bit (Intel)]
- numpy.version.version = 1.6.1
- scipy.version.version =
  0.12.0

Comment: Switch to a UNIX machine. Your problems will go away.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I know. All sorts of problems will go away, not just this one. I've sworn to myself many times that my next machine will be a linux box -- This time I mean it!

Comment: I mean, partitioning your hard drive exists for a reason. Also Ringtail just came out.

Comment: Your SciPy installation seems to be broken. Can you `import scipy.sparse`?

Comment: `import scipy.sparse` gives me `importError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`

Comment: But I can run `import numpy.core.multiarray` without error.

Comment: Do you perhaps have multiple Python installations on your machine and a `PYTHONPATH` that refers to the wrong one?

Answer (score 1):

use PIP installer from  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: Hmm. I've been installing using Christoph Gohlke's windows installers. I'll try uninstalling numpy, scipy, and scikit-learn, and then reinstalling all of them.

Comment: New plan: I'm going to uninstall python and then reinstall everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Raphael, if you're on Windows i highly recommend a prepackaged install, like

PythonXY
https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/

Anaconda
http://www.continuum.io/downloads
(this works on Mac/Linux also)

or
WinPython
https://code.google.com/p/winpython/

the sklearn "stack" comes nicely packaged in all of them

Answer (score -1):

(in Windows7 64bit) As Maxim says you can try Anaconda. (its faster!!!)
It worked for me(updating Anaconda) with a similar problem(DLL import failed/ no module named svm)